# Dart Bech32 and Hex encoding and decoding

Tags: dart, hex, decode, encode

I'm trying to decode this Bech32 address into a hex.
When given cosmos1qpjrq625nglf3xx9chdkq953nhrd3nygte44rt.  It breaks it down into it's head which is 'cosmos' and the remainder is represented as a List of 8-bit unsigned integers (Uint8List).

When this is encoded to hexadecimal (HEX.Encode), i get a value of 00011203001a0a1413081f091106060518170d16000514111317030d11130408.

However, it is meant to be getting me 00643069549a3e9898c5c5db6016919dc6d8cc88 instead.

You can check this if you go to https://slowli.github.io/bech32-buffer/ -> and decode cosmos1qpjrq625nglf3xx9chdkq953nhrd3nygte44rt which gives 00643069549a3e9898c5c5db6016919dc6d8cc88.

I can't figure out the issue, is it perhaps
-The formatting is wrong, different bases? or am i doing this completely wrong.

Thanks and i appreciate any replies
Here is a snippet of code;

```
import 'package:bech32/bech32.dart';
import 'package:hex/hex.dart';

  Bech32Codec bech32codec = Bech32Codec();
  //  target address : 00643069549a3e9898c5c5db6016919dc6d8cc88  -> to get to this address

  String address = 'cosmos1qpjrq625nglf3xx9chdkq953nhrd3nygte44rt';
  Bech32 bech32 = bech32codec.decode(address); 
  print(bech32.data); 
  // this returns [0, 1, 18, 3, 0, 26, 10, 20, 19, 8, 31, 9, 17, 6, 6, 5, 24, 23, 13, 22, 0, 5, 20, 17, 19, 23, 3, 13, 17, 19, 4, 8] 

  print(bech32.hrp);
  print(bech32codec.encode(Bech32("cosmos", bech32.data))); 

  var answer2 = HEX.encode(bech32.data);
  print(answer2);
var decode = HEX.decode('00643069549a3e9898c5c5db6016919dc6d8cc88');

  print(decode);
  // this returns [0, 100, 48, 105, 84, 154, 62, 152, 152, 197, 197, 219, 96, 22, 145, 157, 198, 216, 204, 136]
```

Comment: The bech32 format is not hex-encoded (it's base-32 encoded, not base-16), and the `bech32.data` you have here is not the *bytes*, but the base-32 digits of the address (the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/bech32/latest/bech32/Bech32/data.html) is useless on this, but you can see that all the values are in the range 0..31).  You probably need to combine those 5-bit values into 8-bit bytes in some way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 
I decided to convert both values (bech32.data and decode) into base32 (5bit) which results into 

[6, 0, 5, 20, 17, 19, 23, 3, 13, 17, 19, 4, 8].  

These actually represent the last digits of bech32.data, so i'm somewhere there. But this cuts out the other data from the beginning.